# Issues calculating Red edge inflection point from Sentinel-2 data using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to calculate the Red Edge Inflection Point using Sentinel-2 imagery on GEE. I am relatively new to java script and GEE so forgive me if this is an easy one to solve.

The formula I am trying to calculate is below however, every time I run the script GEE states that there are no bands to display. The formula is:

[image]

And my script is here:

```
var reip = imgMed.expression(('702+40(B4+B7/2) - B5)/ (B6 - B5)'), {
    'B4': imgMed.select(['B4_median']),
    'B7': imgMed.select(['B7_median']), 
    'B6':imgMed.select(['B6_median']),
    'B5':imgMed.select(['B5_median']),
   }).rename('REIP')
   //Display REIP on GEE
Map.addLayer(reip, { palette: ['White', 'orange', 'green']}, 'REIP');
   //Export REIP to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:reip,
  description: '2019_2023REIP',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the expression you're using is different than the equation:

```
'702+40(B4+B7/2) - B5)/(B6 - B5)'
```

Use:

```
'702 + 40*((B4+B7)/2 - B5)/(B6 - B5)'
```

Also, maybe the band name is the issue. We can't know since you didn't share all your code. The following works:

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")

var imageCollection = imageCollection.filterDate("2019-01-01","2023-01-01").filterBounds(AOI);

var reip = function(img){
  return img.expression('702 + 40*((B4+B7)/2 - B5)/(B6 - B5)', {
    'B4': img.select(['B4']),
    'B7': img.select(['B7']), 
    'B6': img.select(['B6']),
    'B5': img.select(['B5']),
   }).rename('REIP');
}

var reipMedian = reip(imageCollection.median()).select('REIP');

   //Display REIP on GEE
Map.addLayer(reipMedian, { palette: ['White', 'orange', 'green'], min: 700, max: 750}, 'REIP');
   //Export REIP to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:reipMedian,
  description: '2019_2023REIP',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However, does it make sense to have high values for water? I thought it would be low values for water. I am new to this metric so trying to make sure I understand it.

Comment: This index and REP (red edge position) index are valid only for pixels with vegetation. The red edge position is related to the [content of chlorophyll](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0176161796802859), so you should filter out pixels without vegetation, as water, snow, concrete, and so on

Comment: Thanks, So I guess this behaviour is normal to have high values on water and concrete? I was thinking maybe the higher values in water was possibly algal blooms but that might have been a stretch.

Comment: RE inflection is related to the pigments (chlorophyll absorbs in red and blue spectrums) and leaf properties (strong reflection in NIR). I don't know if algal blooms reflects on NIR, check what literature says about it